# Issue while configuring multiple persistence units in JPA with JBoss Server

Tags: mysql, jpa, jboss, wildfly

Here I have to connect to multiple databases using JPA say db1, db2. I need  data from table(db2) in my application. So I have configured multiple persistance units for db1 and db2 in persistance.xml file. But I am getting an issue while starting the server saying that:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory.
```

and this is caused by:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [db2_table].
```

Actually it is looking the db2_table in db1, which would be not available. Which means it is not recognising the 2nd persistence unit.

Full trace:

```
14:05:35,409 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."default.war#defaultPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."def.war#defPU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:883)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [def_table]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:880)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? As of now it's a big wall of code that doesn't say anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info :)

Comment: Here I have to connect to multiple databases using JPA say db1,db2 .          I need a data from table(db2) in my application.  so I have configured multiple persistance units  for db1 and db2 in persistance.xml file. but getting an issue while starting the server  saying that javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory.      and   Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [db2_table] .

Comment: Actually it is looking the db2_table in db1, which would be not available.which means it is not recognizing the 2nd persistence unit

Comment: Great! Could you edit your answer to include that? Take note of the formatting options as well so that the big wall of text becomes more comprehensible

Comment: Any help please!!!!!!!!

Comment: Do you have different names for both units in the `persistence.xml` and do you provide these names to appropriate entity managers when injecting/constructing ? `[PersistenceUnit: defPU]` suggests that not necessarily so.

Comment: yeah!! I have given different names for both the persistence units and given the same to the 2 entity managers

Comment: just to confirm is this `PersistenceUnit: defPU` then the name of `db1`? And `db2` has this `def_table`

Comment: persistence unit (1) - defPU  and DB(2) -scheduler ,                         persistence unit (2) - sahaiPU  and DB(2) -sahai

Comment: injecting ? `@PersistenceContext(unitName="")` ?

Comment: sorry , DB(1) -scheduler. Iam not able to inject sahaiPU

Comment: how do you construct `EntityManager` ? And setting `unitName` not `name` ?

Comment: @PersistenceContext(unitName = "defPU ")
 EntityManager em1;                              
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sahaiPU")
 EntityManager em2;

Comment: `defPu ` has a space in name and what is this `sahaiPu`? `scheduler` ?. Is it in persistence.xml ? Maybe you would like to edit the question with the correct `unitNames` and attach `persistence.xml`